# Maven dependency resolved, but still not working in my maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I two maven projects A and B. B is meant to be a service for A, therefore A should depend on B, because it needs to create some objects to send in as an api request to B. Everything seems to work fine: I can  build both projects fine, B shows up in the external libraries of A and the dependency in the pom.xml file is resolved. My IDE even suggests that I import classes from B, but once I import it, IDE says "cannot resolve symbol 'project B's name'". How can I address this issue? (I am using intellij)

This is a snippet of A's pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>B-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and this is a snippet of B's pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>B-project</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0</version>
<name>B-project</name>
<description>B-project service</description>
```

The dependency seems to be resolved until I try to actually import the classes and use them.

if I try to write "SomeClassOfB.someMthod()" my iDE will try to auto-complete with the right class and the right import, but once I finish writing the statement, it says that the symbol 'B-project' cannot be resolved.

I tried rebuilding both projects.

Comment: you'll need to give more specifics. Is this in a test? Is this a project with multiple modules?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added some info, but I'm not really sure what else to add

Comment: ass I asked in my first comment, but differently worded: did you check that the dependency is available in the scope you're working in?

Comment: Yeah it's in the compile scope (which is the one that I want)

Comment: which is the one you want, ok, but is it also the one you need? That was the point of the question. also, having it in one module doesn't mean you have it in another, which is why I informed whether or not it's a project with multiple modules

Comment: both are single module projects

Comment: What happens if you run `mvn package` in the A project directory? It's not clear whether this is a maven configuration issue or an idea issue.

Comment: I not sure what to look for exactly, but ```mvn package``` without a problem and no mention of project B is found in the log. For now, the project works because I copied B's classes in project A and this is what I'm trying to solve.